# Query Of Queries runtime error.Cannot apply the binary numeric operator [*|/] on a non numeric type

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, qoq

I have a script that queries the database for order information and then a query of that query in order to get order totals. The code looks like this.

```
<!--- Retrieve order information from database --->
<CFQUERY  NAME="GetOrder">
  SELECT 
    oi.OrderQty, oi.ItemPrice
  FROM 
    Orders o,
    OrderItems oi, 
  WHERE 
    o.ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ATTRIBUTES.OrderID#">
    AND o.ID   = oi.OrderID
</CFQUERY>

<!--- Query the GetOrders query to find total $$ --->
<CFQUERY DBTYPE="Query" NAME="GetTotal">
  SELECT SUM(ItemPrice * OrderQty) AS OrderTotal
  FROM GetOrder
</CFQUERY>
```

The itemPrice and OrderQty fields in the database are both set as numeric Data Types. For some reason when I run the script I get the error, "Query Of Queries runtime error. Cannot apply the binary numeric operator [*|/] on a non numeric type"

I even ran a quick check to see if the numbers were numeric in the query and aborted the script before the query of queries. The check I ran looks like this.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfif isnumeric(GetOrder.OrderQty)>1<cfelse>0</cfif>
<cfif isnumeric(GetOrder.ItemPrice)>1<cfelse>0</cfif>
<cfabort>
</cfoutput>
```

Both results of the cfifs came back as "1"

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your test is only testing the first row in your query, subsequent rows could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the Query of Queries and cfloop your query to do the same thing, preferably using `precisionEvaluate()` to avoid floating point rounding error.

```
<cfset orderTotal = 0>
<cfloop query="GetOrder">
    <cfset orderTotal = precisionEvaluate(orderTotal + (ItemPrice * OrderQty))>
</cfloop>
```

Why it didn't work could be because of a number of things.  Maybe your DB driver did not return the correct sql type.

The `isnumeric` code only tests if the string is numeric, not the internal representation of that string in the query object.